# Complex Logic quires on simple mongo document

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am battling with forming complex logic queries on very basic data types in mongo. Essentially I can have millions of user attributes so my basic mongo document is:

```
{
   name: "Gender"
   value: "Male"
   userId : "ABC123"
}

{
   name: "M-Spike"
   value: 0.123
   userId : "ABC123"
}
```

What I would like to do is search for things like findAll userId where {name : "Gender, value: "Male"} AND { name : "m-spike", value : { $gt : 0.1} }

I have tried using the aggregation framework but the complexity of the queries is limited, basically I was ORing all the criteria and counting the results by sampleId (which replicated a rudimentary AND)

Comment: are you using 2.1 version and the new aggregation framework?

Comment: Yes I've started using it but doesn't really get me exactly what I want @AsyaKamsky

Comment: I'm surprised at the structure of your schema - unless each user can have thousands of attributes, I would think it more natural to have all attributes for a single user in one document...  Do you know all the names of attribute the user will have?  If so it may be possible to use aggregation framework for this

Comment: Its possible for a user to have millions of attributes, i'm using it to store genomic data, so there maybe a attribute for a clinical param which will typically be in the range of 100's and then genomic data which may have a point to describe each of the millions of variances in your genome. Generally I will not know the names of the attributes in advance, as in it should be possible to add new ones

Answer (score 0):

I can see a way to do it for N being the number of attributes you want to query about (N being 2 in your example).  Try something like this:

```
 db.collection.aggregate(
      [  {  $match:  {$or: [ 
                        {"name":"M-Spike","value":{$gt:.1}},
                        {"name":"Gender","value":"Male"}
                           ] 
                     } 
         },   
         {  $group: { _id:"$userId",total:{$sum:1}}  
         },
         { $project: { _id:1, 
                       matchedAttr : { $eq: ["$total",2] }   
                     } 
         }
      ]
 )
```

You will get back:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "XYZ123",
            "matchedAttr" : false
        },
        {
            "_id" : "ABC123",
            "matchedAttr" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Now, if you had 2 conditions you matched via "$or" then you get back true for _id that matched both of them.  So for five conditions, your $match: $or array will have five conditional pairs, and the last $project transformation will be `$eq: ["$total",5]`

Built in to this solution is the assumption that you cannot have duplicate entries (i.e. _id cannot have "M-Spike":.5 and also "M-Spike":.2.   If you can, then this won't work.

Comment: Yea so far I have something almost identical to this. This effectively produces a logical AND I don't believe it holds true if you want to do this in combination with an OR. For instance  OR ( AND ("name":"M-Spike","value":{$gt:.1}},                   {"name":"Gender","value":"Male"}), {"name":"KRAS","value":{$gt:12.4}})

Comment: Have you seen a schema like this? Do you think it is a reasonable approach?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a reasonable schema for flexible querying.  What exactly would the "or" query be like?  If it has all these attributes or all those attributes?

Comment: exactly....this querying is for selecting groups of patients based on various attributes be it clinical params, genomic data or patient characteristics

Comment: I would definitely consider a different structure for the document - in particular I would try to have one document per user with nameofattribute: value array if that's possible as that would allow querying in multiple ways.  but there may be trade offs to that.

Comment: I came across this recently which may help a lot in your use case if you can adjust the query slightly: http://chemeo.com/doc/technology